# Driver's License

Tags: philippines

My husband has 2 driver's license a German one and an International driver's license, we are staying here in the Philippines for one year. Since he is only allowed to drive 90 days. What is your proposal or advise so he can drive longer than 90 days.
Please acknowledge and send me requirements in case he needs to secure a local driver's license.

Comment: a so-called 'international driver's license' isn't a driver's license at all. It's merely a sheet of translations of what's on your actual driver's license.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely yes, he'll need to get a driver's license from the Philippine authorities. This isn't special for the Philippines, most countries only allow driving on a foreign license for a limited period, after which conversion to a local one is required.

Best way to get that is to contact them directly and ask how to go about things. Maybe the German consulate can help, or a local police station in the Philippines.

Many countries also have reciprocal agreements, allowing easy issuing of a license for holders of licenses of those other countries. Again, the relevant authorities in the Philippines and/or the German consulate should be able to assist you.